# iOS - Is it possible to share UIImage with text to Facebook in iOS 5?

Tags: ios, facebook, ios5

I would like to share an image (an UIImage) with some pre-defined text to Facebook. I achieved this in iOS 6.0 and afterwards with the Social Framework. However this is not available in iOS 5, so I would like to know if this is possible. I considered the web dialog but seems it only support to share image through an URL, but not an UIImage.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
NSString *texttoshare = @"Your text";
UIImage *imagetoshare = [[UIImage alloc]init];
imagetoshare=[UIImage imageNamed:@"shareImage.png"];
NSArray *activityItems = @[texttoshare, imagetoshare];
UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:nil];
activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypeAssignToContact, UIActivityTypePrint];
[self presentViewController:activityVC animated:TRUE completion:nil];
```

Hope this will helpful to you...
Thank you

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but when I try this on iOS 5.1.1 device, it crashes whenever this code segment is called. It works fine on 6.0 though.

Comment: Then do one thing. Add an exception breakpoint and find out where the crash occurs and see the crash log results...